# How to generate .classpath file using ant target?

Tags: eclipse, ant, classpath

I am working on a legacy project where all the build is happening using ant build scripts. The java classpath is defined in  element of ant. I need to generate .classpath file which should have all the references of jars and classes referred to by `<path>` element so that I can work with the project in eclipse.

Is there a macro or task available in ANT for this?

How to do this?

Comment: No, there is not Ant task. I don't know of anything that would do this.

Comment: You can use [`<pathconvert>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) for that with `pathsep="&quot;/>&lt;classpathentry kind=&quot;lib&quot; path=&quot;"` to generate the part for the JARs. For more help, please show your Ant script you have so far and tell how the JARs and class folder(s or source folders?) are given and if they are located inside or outside of the project.